# is it possible to get the doc compile success or failed flag when using xelatex to compile tex document

Tags: xetex

I am using xelatex to compile some tex document, I was wonder is there any way to know the compile success or facing error? Because I am programming automatcially compile latex docuemnt with a cloud way. When we using texstudio or any other tools to compile the document, we can read the document and found the error log to know the compile facing issue. But with the programming way, how to know the compile success or contains error with a reliable way? this is the rust code I am using right now to compile the tex document:

```
let cmd = Command::new("xelatex")
        .arg("-output-directory")
        .arg(compile_out_path.clone())
        .arg(params.file_path.clone())
        .current_dir(current_dir)
        .output();
    if let Err(e) = cmd {
        error!("compile tex file failed: {}, parmas: {:?}", e, params);
        return;
    }
```

this code only knows when the command run failed, but could not know the compile command complete but the tex document compile failed issue. is it possible to parse the log to know the success or failed flag?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, but `xelatex` produces the standard return values of `0` and `1`. Can't you just test for those?

Comment: ok, I will try what you said.